# Primefaces ajax event change one menu select

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.

I want to call the Listener when a selection is made, the listener is called but it return a null object;

I have the following in my JSF page

```
<ui:define name="page-content">
        <h:form prependId="false">
            <p:commandButton image="back" ajax="false" immediate="true" style="margin-right:20px;" value="#{phasemsgs['navigation.back']}" action="/boo/viewMesTaches.xhtml"/>

            <p:panel header="#{phasemsgs['tache.title']} Details" style="margin-top:10px">
                <p:messages />
                <h:panelGrid id="detail" columns="2" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="label,value">
                    <h:outputText value="#{phasemsgs['tache.nomtache.title']}:" />
                            <h:inputText id="phase_nomtache" value="#{TacheComponent.tache.nomtache}" required="false" label="phase_nomtache" />
<h:outputText value="Projet :*" />

                    <h:selectOneMenu id="selectProjet"
                        value="#{ProjetComponent.projet.idprojet}" required="false">

                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{ProjetComponent.listProjets()}"
                            var="projet" itemValue="#{projet.idprojet}"
                            itemLabel="#{projet.nomprojet}" />
                            <p:ajax listener="#{ProjetComponent.onProjetChange()}"
                            update="selectPhase" />

                        <f:converter converterId="entityConverter" />

                    </h:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText value="Phase :*" />

                <h:selectOneMenu id="selectPhase"
                        value="#{TacheComponent.tache.phase.idphase}" required="false">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{ProjetComponent.listPhases}" var="phase"
                        itemValue="#{phase}" itemLabel="#{phase.typephase}" />
                        <f:converter converterId="entityConverter" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>

                </h:panelGrid>
```

and this is the method onProjetChange in my Component:

```
@Scope("session")
@Component("ProjetComponent")
public class ProjetComponentImpl implements ProjetComponent {
    private Projet projet;
    List<Phase> listPhases;
    @Autowired
    private ProjetDAO projetDAO;
        getters and setters ..
    public ProjetComponentImpl() {
    }
    @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            //initialize the data here

            this.projet=new Projet();
            this.listPhases=new ArrayList<Phase>();
        }

    public void onProjetChange() {
            if(projet !=null && !projet.equals(""))
            {
               listPhases = new ArrayList<Phase> (projet.getPhases());
            System.out.println("onProjetChange Clause if:" + projet.getNomprojet());

            }
            else{
                listPhases = new ArrayList<Phase>();
                System.out.println("onprojetChange else:"+projet.getNomprojet());

            }
```

and this is the stack trace:

```
onProjetChange Clause if:null
```

and this is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jaqen H'ghar said, you are not setting a Phase object to your Bean.

Since you provide a List as select option

```
<f:selectItems value="#{ProjetComponent.listPhases}" .../>
```

You were supposed to feed the selected item back to your bean

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{TacheComponent.selectedPhase}" ..>
```

where, you are also supposed to have a get/set for selectedPhase in your Bean named 'TacheComponent'

```
    private Phase selectedPhase;
public Phase getSelectedPhase() {
    return selectedPhase;
}
public void setSelectedPhase(Phase selectedPhase) {
    this.selectedPhase = selectedPhase;
}
```

One last thing, is that your **Phase** Class is probably a **Pojo**, **not a String** Object, so you cannot use it with p:selectXYZ components without using a **converter**. I suspect that this is the reason tried setting a `phase.idphase` (which I also suspect is a String property) at some point, then you tried using a converter, but you probably did not set it right. Since you don't provide code for your *entityConverter*, it's hard to tell what you did wrong.

Using a converter is a pretty much straightforward job. You just really need to spend 10 minutes to understand how they work, and you're good to go. There's a ton of tutorials on Converters, for example you can try [this one](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly I think you have to bind directly to the entity on the bean, not to its id. So, use

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectProjet" value="#{ProjetComponent.projet}" required="false">
```

and

```
itemValue="#{projet}"
```

That way, the entityconverter will do the job.